# convert uint32 bits to float in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to extract the float value of a `uint32` number using numpy.
I construct the numpy array of `uint32` concatenating 4 `uint8` like so,

```
u_arr = np.array([10,2,4,8], "uint8")
arr = (np.array(u_arr[0],"uint32") << 24) + (np.array(u_arr[1],"uint32") << 16) + (np.array(u_arr[2],"uint32") << 8) + (np.array(u_arr[3],"uint32"))
val_f = arr.astype(float) ## gives me the float of the uint32 which is wrong 
## arr, val_f = (167904264, 167904264.0)
```

How can I get the float value back stored by the `uint32` in `arr`?

Comment: "arr" is of type numpy.int64. Do you know what is your expected value for the float ?

Comment: I just noticed that too .. it should be uint32 and the float is float32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it do the job ?

```
import numpy as np
import struct

def numpy_int64_bits_to_float(numpy_int64_value):
    bytes_object = struct.pack(">l", numpy_int64_value)
    float_value = struct.unpack(">f", bytes_object)[0]
    return float_value

u_arr = np.array([63,128,0,0], "uint8")
arr = (np.array(u_arr[0],"uint32") << 24) + (np.array(u_arr[1],"uint32") << 16) + (np.array(u_arr[2],"uint32") << 8) + (np.array(u_arr[3],"uint32"))
val_f = numpy_int64_bits_to_float(arr)
```

"l" is for "long" c type and "f" is for "float".
"q" is for "long long" c type and "d" is for double.
These are "format characters".
Be sure to check the types you give to the function and/or adapt the format-characters.
You can check the doc here : https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct-format-strings.

The use of ">" is to ensure that the byte order is "big-endian" (same source).

Comment: something is off here .. Logic seems correct .. [63,128,0,0] should be 1.0 but it gives `5.263544247e-315`

Comment: I edited my code with your values and so changed types, is what you're looking for ?